# index.php:212 Uncaught ReferenceError: FusionCharts is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i want to retrieve data from mysql database into bar chart using Fusion chart. but i get this error when try to debug with console log (ctrl+shift+j in chrome):
index.php:212 Uncaught ReferenceError: FusionCharts is not defined

here is my code so far

```
<?php
                            include "../../koneksi.php";
                            //require_once __DIR__ . '/fusioncharts.php';
                            include "fusioncharts.php";

                        // Form the SQL query that returns the top 10 most populous countries
                          $strQuery = mysql_query("select calType, count(cal_num) as count from calequipment Group By CalType order by calType desc");

                          // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
                          if ($strQuery) {
                            // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
                            $arrData = array(
                              "chart" => array(
                                  "caption" => "Calibration Type",
                                  "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
                                  "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
                                  "borderAlpha"=> "20",
                                  "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
                                  "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
                                  "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
                                  "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
                                  "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
                                  "showValues" => "0",
                                  "divlineColor" => "#999999",
                                  "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
                                  "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
                                )
                            );

                            $arrData["data"] = array();

                            // Push the data into the array
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($strQuery)) {
                              array_push($arrData["data"], array(
                                  "label" => $row["calType"],
                                  "value" => $row["count"]
                                  )
                              );
                            }

                            /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */

                            $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

                            /*Create an object for the column chart using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor. Syntax for the constructor is ` FusionCharts("type of chart", "unique chart id", width of the chart, height of the chart, "div id to render the chart", "data format", "data source")`. Because we are using JSON data to render the chart, the data format will be `json`. The variable `$jsonEncodeData` holds all the JSON data for the chart, and will be passed as the value for the data source parameter of the constructor.*/

                            $columnChart = new FusionCharts("Pie3D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

                            // Render the chart
                            $columnChart->render();

                          }
                        ?>
```

the error said in line 212 and line 217. this the code :

```
212. <div class="panel panel-default">
217. <?php
```

its not make sense so i feel confused

i sure that the path includes correctly. please anyone help me. every suggestion would be appreciate thanks :)

edit:
i got something different between my php file and console log file. i mean when i try to see the code in console log, the error is in this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            new FusionCharts({"type":"Pie3D","id":"myFirstChart","width":600,"height":300,"renderAt":"chart-1","dataFormat":"json","dataSource":{"chart":{"caption":"Calibration Type","paletteColors":"#0075c2","bgColor":"#ffffff","borderAlpha":"20","canvasBorderAlpha":"0","usePlotGradientColor":"0","plotBorderAlpha":"10","showXAxisLine":"1","xAxisLineColor":"#999999","showValues":"0","divlineColor":"#999999","divLineIsDashed":"1","showAlternateHGridColor":"0"},"data":[{"label":"Internal","value":"1"},{"label":"External","value":"2"}]}});
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            FusionCharts("myFirstChart").render();
        });
    </script>
```

but that code is very different with my php file when i open in notepad++

Comment: Are you sure "fusioncharts.php" is in the same directory as this file ? Are you sure that "fusioncharts.php" declares the class FusionCharts ? You could try to replace "include" by "require", in order to get a proper error if the file is not found.

Comment: i've tried before, please see my code. because i've tried to replace "include" by "require" is not work, so i comment that line.

Comment: i have edit my question, try to see on the last paragraph